# Reading in .nc file in R

Tags: raster

I am attempting to read in a .nc file using raster:

```
rn = raster("A20022642019354.L3b_SCAU_CHL.x.nc")
```

but get the following:

> Error in ncvar_type_to_string(rv$precint) :
> Error, unrecognized type code of variable supplied: -1

Any solutions?

Comment: Explore this link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DvfTZSJLRfw

Comment: Tried the method in the link, but still get the same error.